# jQuery binding AJAX events without DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the [documentation of jQuery AJAX Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) all the examples use a *jQuery DOM Element* for declare a binding like this:

```
$('.log').ajaxSend( hander );
```

I want to catch *jQuery AJAX Events* without the need of having a DOM Element to attach them, like this:

```
$.ajaxSend( function( event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions ){
  console.log( "ajaxSend" );
  console.log( "ajaxSend.event", event );
  console.log( "ajaxSend.jqXHR", jqXHR );
  console.log( "ajaxSend.ajaxOptions", ajaxOptions );
});
```

But It looks like it doesn't work:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'ajaxSend'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have jQuery on your page.

Comment: @Jeff: The function displayed by the TypeError is the jQuery function *(obfuscated)*. The jQuery function is also a namespace for other functions and data. The error is because there's no `ajaxSend` method on that namespace.

Comment: @amnotiam Yeah, I noticed that. I dont have a better answer though. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `document`:

```
$(document).ajaxSend( hander );
```

Comment: Very nice workaround, I'll let the question opened for a while waiting for solution without _workaround_, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to customize your ajax call in which using the $.fn.ajax call works great:

```
$.ajax('{your_url}', options);
```

Comment: Nop, I want to bind all the AJAX vents to build a console debug like this https://gist.github.com/3182810